# How to get response of a function in another file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two files named `actions.js` and `vip.js`. I have declared a function `fetchVip` in `action` file and imported it in `vip` file which will populate text element when screen is loaded. I want to access `fetchVip` response in `vip` file but i get undefined like this  `LOG  useeffect undefined`. While respone works as expected in action file.My code is below.

**Vip File**

```
import {fetchVip} from '../../Store/action';

const Vip = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useeffect', fetchVip());
  }, [fetchVip()]);
```

**action file**

```
export const fetchVip = () => {
  axios
    .post(`${baseUrl}/get-vips`)
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
      return {type: 'ERROR', payload: error};
    });
};
```

Comment: fetchVip() doesn't return the axios call. That's not enough though, you also need to use an async function in your useEffect function and await the call to fetchVip(). Also, what is your Store? Is that redux? If so, you should use a selector instead.

Comment: yes i have redux. but i thought using return with fetchVip in useEffect is less code and will be more efficient. correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: With redux it works like this: 1) useEffect dispatches a fetchVip action when the component mounts 2) this causes an axios request which updates the store 3) your component re-renders because of the selector getting the updated VIP info from the store

Answer (score 0):

`fetchVip` does not return anything, so you have to add a return statement here first:

```
export const fetchVip = () => {
  return axios
    .post(`${baseUrl}/get-vips`)
```

or remove the curly braces, then it will return as well.

```
export const fetchVip = () => axios
    .post(`${baseUrl}/get-vips`)
...
      return {type: 'ERROR', payload: error};
    })
```

Now it will return a promise. That means that the result will not be there right away, but at some point later in time. Therefore, if you want to use it in the `useEffect`, you have to await for the result to arrive.

you could to this with the ES6 syntax:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getVip = async () => {
      const vip = await fetchUsers();
      console.log(vip)
      //now you can do something with it
    };

    getVip();

  }, [fetchVip]);
```

or the `promise-then` syntax:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchVip().then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      //do something with the result
    })
    
  }, [fetchVip]);
```

This is wrong btw. remove the (). You want to check for the function here, not the result of the function.

```
}, [fetchVip()]);
```